# Having Post Name in the url without rewriting current url structure

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Is it possible to have something like this in wordpress:

http://example.com/post/2135/**post-name**

without having to rewrite my current url structure which is

http://example.com/post/**2135**

I want to keep it, and be able to access posts both ways. With and without the **post-name**

is it possible to have it that way? maybe make wordpress ignore that there's the post name attached at the end?

Answer (score 0):

i believe it is in the php.ini file

example,
me.com/boss

file structure

root/boss/index.php

the index.php file will auto load.

but if you are used MVC you can change the results of what is displayed.

but 
can you use http://example.com.post/2135/index.php&postname=lol